# How to add/edit values in /etc/profiles.d or in bashrc programmatically?

Tags: java, linux

I have a requirement to install java, Jenkins, maven and some other software on RHEL linux remote system. So far I am able to perform the following:

1. Copy jdk to Linux and set the path variable
2. Install Jenkins on the server using "sudo yum -y install jenkins"

Now the problem is that when I am trying to start jenkins as a service using "service start jenkins" I am getting an error and this got resolved after changing Jenkins user to root user and providing path of java in /etc/* (not sure exactly where).

Instead of doing this manually is there a way to add these information to /etc/* or to bashrc programmatically?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: What error you were getting? This is probably related to execution access on the jenkins service file. chmod +x <service file> should help if that's the case.

Comment: Starting jenkins (via systemctl):  Job for jenkins.service failed. See 'systemctl status jenkins.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
                                                           [FAILED]                                                               is The error. After adding the java path and changing the user from jenkins user to root user it worked. This change was done manually in some file under /etc.* I some how want to avoid manual intervention. hence need some advice on how to achieve this

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions???